# How to remotely add reservation to DHCP Server using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, dhcp, remote

Administrators have restricted RDP access to our DHCP server.

I need to add an IP address reservation for a MAC address.

How do I remotely add an IP address reservation on the DHCP server using PowerShell?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dhcpserver/add-dhcpserverv4reservation?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Answer (score 1):

Use [Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dhcpserver/add-dhcpserverv4reservation):

```
Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ScopeId 10.10.10.0 -IPAddress 10.10.10.8 -ClientId "F0-DE-F1-7A-00-5E"
```

You can also run it against a remote DHCP server using the `-ComputerName` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You coild also rekord powershell using invoke-command and then then commando provided earlier

```
    $ComputerName = "DHCP_Server_Name"
    $ReservationParams = @{
        ScopeId = "Your_DHCP_Scope_ID"
        IPAddress = "Reserved_IP_Address"
        ClientId = "MAC_Address"
        HostName = "Client_Host_Name"
    }
    
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
    param($ReservationParams)
    Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation @ReservationParams
} -ArgumentList $ReservationParams
```

Keep in mind that invoke-command is part of remote powershell and that has some requirements